# Finding sum of series with variable

Tags: calculus

Find the sum of the series. For what values of the variable does the series converge to this sum?

$$1+\frac{x} {2}+\frac{x^2} {4}+\frac{x^3} {8}...$$

Summation notation: $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n} {2^n}$

I know you use the formula $\frac{a} {1-r}$ to find the sum of geometric series but I'm confused about the x

Comment: Just write it $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^n$. You have a geometric series with $r=\frac{x}{2}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{2^n} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty y^n$, where $y = x/2$. The series converges when $|x|/2 = |y| < 1$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: prove by induction that $$\sum_{n=0}^m\frac{x^n}{2^n}=-\frac{2^{-m} \left(2^{m+1}-x^{m+1}\right)}{x-2}$$